# Could not install packages due to an Environment Error: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Tags: 20.04, apache2, amazon-ec2, aws

I am trying to install the terserflow. I have a t2.xlarge instance type but every time I get an error.

Can you please help me with how much storage I have to take?

`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device:`

```
`df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       7.6G  4.2G  3.4G  56% /
devtmpfs        7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.6G  864K  1.6G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       25M   25M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/6312
/dev/loop1       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1891
/dev/loop2       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/lxd/24061
/dev/loop3       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2745
/dev/loop4       54M   54M     0 100% /snap/snapd/19122
/dev/xvda15     105M  6.1M   99M   6% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000`
```

Comment: 7.6G is much smaller than the recommended size of any current release of Ubuntu.